# Windows 2012 R2 - Intermediate cert keeps reappearing in root store

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate

I have an issue with a particular Windows 2012 R2 server. For some reason, the Comodo intermediate cert keeps getting automatically installed in the root store instead of the intermediate store (where it also exists).

I have tried both deleting it and disabling all purposes for it. After a few days, the cert either reappears or is re-enabled, all on its own.

This is the cert:

```
COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Thumbprint: ‎afe5d244a8d1194230ff479fe2f897bbcd7a8cb4
```

What can I do to find out why this thing keeps reappearing, and why it's ending up in the root store every time???

Answer (score 0):

The COMODO RSA Certification Authority has [two certificates](https://ssl-tools.net/subjects/5e021b686c5cd3be1691995789dfc41472163d03).

One is the original COMODO RSA Certification Authority and was issued in the year 2000. However, it was a subordinate CA certificate, signed (using SHA1) by **AddTrust External CA Root**, and therefore appears as an Intermediate in Windows.

The one with the fingerprint you quoted was issued in 2010 as a self-signed root CA certificate, which explains why it appears in your Trusted Root CA store in Windows.

When it reappears, move it to the **Untrusted Certificates** store.  It's probably reappearing due to the [Windows Root Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx) updates.

Note that as long as two certificates have the same Distinguished Name and the same private key, then they are the same certificates - one cannot be the root of your Comodo cert without the other also being the root.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to find out why it keeps reappearing. It's breaking the chain because this magically reappearing cert is not actually the root for our Comodo SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9774/2238/incomplete-certificate-chain-on-windows-servers

It recommends keeping the cert in the store but disabling its use for all purposes.  This way, you don't remove the cert and it won't be re-added.

Comment: Try to add a summary of the link on your answer and add the link as a reference. If the site goes down your answer is meaningless.

Comment: As I mentioned right in my question, I have tried disabling it but the cert gets re-enabled on its own. In the end, I disabled automatic root certificate updates in Windows Server.